# Twitter Bootstrap - min-width: 980px responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I haven't actually found any responsive options for in Twitter bootsrap for the 980px - 1199px. Where can I get it, or where can I set the properties for it?

I can only see properties for min width: 1200px and min width: 768 - 979, but where is the one between them?

Comment: in the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file, you should find the `@media` queries. you can add your custom one their. `980px` pretty much covers modern day screen sizes anyway, so there isn't any need to declare a query for them

Comment: You can customize the sizes here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html and this is a really good tool too to get the numbers to feed in to Bootstrap http://gridcalculator.dk

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have understood your question correctly, you are looking for a media query between 1200px and 980px?

There should be one there as default by bootstrap but if not then you can create one very easily yourself by using the follow code:

```
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
     /* content goes here */
}
```